# Sending a push notification to an inactive user on android

Tags: android, push-notification, user-inactivity

Is it possible to send a push notification to a user after they have left an android app for a defined period of time?

Comment: what research have you done so far?

Comment: depends on if the key is still valid for that user

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course!

You should suscribe your android to your GcmBroadcastReceiver class. 
and add the permission

Your class will tell when a push message arrives, and be handled by your class in your app.

Here is an example:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm pretty new to Android development so please forgive my ignorance. What do you mean by subscribe your android to your GcmBroadcastReceiver class?

Comment: i asume you are using GCM yo implement the push service...here you can find how to implement it. You will se, you have the GcmBroadcastReciever. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html